# C# calculate the height of a string in with the given width

Tags: c#, string, graphics, fonts, measure

Im trying to write text in C# so that it spans the required width (approximately).

To write text you need to specify the height. So I need to know what height would make it write to the desired length.

```
Font myFont = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, unknown);   
gc.DrawString(LabelText, myFont, gBrush, 0, 0);
```

Ive found the following, but it requires FONT, which requires height. Which defeats the whole point?

```
gc.MeasureString(LabelText, new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 12), length);
```

How would I determine the required height to make for example "I am a String" stretch 50px.

Comment: `MeasureString` with several different font point sizes and select the best one.

Comment: So its trial and error? Im drawing lots of strings.. of different sizes, surely measuring many times for each one isnt the best way?

Comment: It isn't efficient, but if you start with a reasonable size (possibly derived from the width in pixels), you can minimize trials.

Comment: I've done your suggestion in a while Loop. Ever increasing font size til it becomes bigger than desired width. It works good considering :) Thanks.

Comment: The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10382725/1583) from @John Koerner has an interesting idea - using the ratio of the width/height of one `MeasureString` in order to determine an optimal size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an example on the site [switchonthecode](https://web.archive.org/web/20090720050946/http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-font-scaling) (note - archived version).  They provide a method that takes a minimum and maximum font size along with the size of your area.  It tries the minimum size and from there determines the ratio of the font and then determines the best size for you.